# How can graphic objects be drawn in AnyLogic during runtime?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to add reactangles to the graphic screen in Anylogic during runtime. This is what I have so far:

```
ShapeRectangle a = new ShapeRectangle(SHAPE_DRAW_2D ,true,
                                         10,
                                         10,
                                         2,
                                         0,
                                         black,
                                         black,
                                         20,
                                         20,
                                         5,
                                         0.5,
                                         LINE_STYLE_SOLID);
```

I bet the object is created. However, it is not printed on the canvas. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing that you need to add the shape to the presentation like this:

```
presentation.add(a);
```